# using a Pixel 2 without Google account

Tags: google

I would like to buy a Pixel 2 but use it without signing in to a Google account. I would get apps from F-Droid, for example. I do not wish to use any Google apps. I also do not wish to use a custom ROM. My questions:

- does this work?
- would I receive OS updates?
- are there any problems to be expected when using a Pixel 2 without ever signing in to Google?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use an Android without a Google account, but it would not be a "fun" experience.

You will need a 3rd party app store in order to download apps (apk download sites will work, too).

I think you will receive OS updates (not sure).

Now for the 3rd question: are there any problems? Yes, there will be. Some apps ask you to sign in to Google - you won't be able to use those apps. Some apps ask you to have Google Play Games - they will work, but you will not get achievements. In addition, items like contacts and downloaded apps will not sync, making it hard to transfer to a new phone (without Wi-Fi and Bluetooth).

Overall: it is possible, but would not be a good idea.